# Section 80 of Dirac's book: Principles of Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian, gauge-invariance

I am looking for informations about one of Dirac's calculation: in his book *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* (4th edition), he developed inside section 80 a gauge-invariant version of QED in which he gets a curious term in his new hamiltonian $H^*$ which he qualified as "strange" for a relativistic theory because it corresponds to "an energy associated with the instantaneous propagation of forces". I believe that he did not write about it again in the following of the book.

Does anyone have informations about this "strange" term?